# preg_match array items in string?

Tags: php, algorithm, preg-match, string-parsing

Lets say I have an array of bad words:

```
$badwords = array("one", "two", "three");
```

And random string:

```
$string = "some variable text";
```

How to create this cycle:

```
if (one or more items from the $badwords array is found in $string)
echo "sorry bad word found";
else
echo "string contains no bad words";
```

Example:
if `$string = "one fine day" or "one fine day two of us did something"`, user should see sorry bad word found message.
If `$string = "fine day"`, user should see string contains no bad words message.

As I know, you can't `preg_match` from array. Any advices?

Comment: $string is allways a random string, Its a search query to be more specific. So if visitor enters query containing bad words, he should see no results, else.. Well you got the point? :)

Comment: And **yes you can `preg_match`** an array, you just need to implode it first. Check my answer given.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
$badWords = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$stringToCheck = 'some stringy thing';
// $stringToCheck = 'one stringy thing';

$noBadWordsFound = true;
foreach ($badWords as $badWord) {
  if (preg_match("/\b$badWord\b/", $stringToCheck)) {
    $noBadWordsFound = false;
    break;
  }
}
if ($noBadWordsFound) { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: I used your code for Arabic strings and it worked fine. next day i tried to run the code without any modification but gives me wrong result. the problem is in the preg_match function. any help please?

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to use `preg_match()` here?
What about this:

```
foreach($badwords as $badword)
{
  if (strpos($string, $badword) !== false)
    echo "sorry bad word found";
  else
    echo "string contains no bad words";
}
```

If you need `preg_match()` for some reasons, you can generate regex pattern dynamically. Something like this:

```
$pattern = '/(' . implode('|', $badwords) . ')/'; // $pattern = /(one|two|three)/
$result = preg_match($pattern, $string);
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check each word by exploding the string into words, you can use this:

```
$badwordsfound = count(array_filter(
    explode(" ",$string),
    function ($element) use ($badwords) {
        if(in_array($element,$badwords)) 
            return true; 
        }
    })) > 0;

if($badwordsfound){
   echo "Bad words found";
}else{
   echo "String clean";
}
```

Now, something better came to my mind, how about replacing all the bad words from the array and check if the string stays the same?

```
$badwords_replace = array_fill(0,count($badwords),"");
$string_clean = str_replace($badwords,$badwords_replace,$string);
if($string_clean == $string) {
    echo "no bad words found";
}else{
    echo "bad words found";
}
```

Comment: I suggest splitting on something like '\b', otherwise bad words will run wild when followed by comma or other separators. )

Comment: Hey look at the second solution I've added before accepting :D

Comment: be careful of the "clbuttic mistake" with this solution.

Comment: Yea, I realized that (clbuttic) and then wrote the second solution which I think is very practical to solve it. Thanks @JTSmith.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bad word filter I use and it works great:

```
private static $bad_name = array("word1", "word2", "word3");

// This will check for exact words only. so "ass" will be found and flagged 
// but not "classic"

$badFound = preg_match("/\b(" . implode(self::$bad_name,"|") . ")\b/i", $name_in);
```

Then I have another variable with select strings to match:

```
// This will match "ass" as well as "classic" and flag it

private static $forbidden_name = array("word1", "word2", "word3");

$forbiddenFound = preg_match("/(" . implode(self::$forbidden_name,"|") . ")/i", $name_in);
```

Then I run an `if` on it:

```
if ($badFound) {
   return FALSE;
} elseif ($forbiddenFound) {
   return FALSE;
} else {
   return TRUE;
}
```

Hope this helps.  Ask if you need me to clarify anything.