# Search variable content for specific matches

Tags: php, variables, foreach

i have the fowling code in my project:

```
 $title = "In this title we have the word GUN"
 $needed_words = array('War', 'Gun', 'Shooting');
 foreach($needed_words as $needed_word) {
     if (preg_match("/\b$needed_word\b/", $title)) {
     $the_word = "ECHO THE WORD THATS FIND INSIDE TITLE";
     }
 }
```

I want to check if `$title` contains one of 15 predefined words, 
for example lets say:
if `$title` contains words **"War, Gun, Shooting"** then i want to assign the word that is find to `$the_word`

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: the only think that comes in my mind is to check for every word with if/elseif - but i dont thnik this is the right solution...

Comment: Take look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words

Comment: NO.. NO.. this is right one..http://stackoverflow.com/a/10358573/2611927

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use regular expressions, as it is most flexible, and allows you to have more controll over the words which you like to match. To be sure that the string contains words like `gun` (but also `guns`), `shoot` (but also `shooting`) you can do the following:

```
$words = array(
    'war',
    'gun',
    'shoot'
);

$pattern = '/(' . implode(')|(', $words) . ')/i';

$if_included = (bool) preg_match($pattern, "Some text - here");
var_dump($if_included);
```

This matches more then it should. For example it will return `true` also if the string contains a `warning` (becouse it starts with `war`) you can improve this by introducing additinal constraints to certain patterns. For example:

```
$words = array(
    'war(?![a-z])', // now it will match "war", but not "warning"
    'gun',
    'shoot'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$makearray=array('war','gun','shooting');
$title='gun';
if(in_array($title,$makearray))
{
$if_included='the value you want to give';
echo $if_included;
}
```

Note:- This will work if your `$title` contains exactly the same string that is present as one of the value in the array.**Otherwise not**.

Comment: Isn't going to work. "war gun" doesn't have "gun" in it according to this code.